Connecting to Multiple Broadcasted Streams in Flink
I have a user-case in Flink where I need to connect to 2 Broadcast streams to perform a certain KeyedProcessFunction operation. Does Flink allow this? I'm unable to see any API that supports multiple broadcast streams in one ProcessFunction.

How do I achieve the above usecase in Flink?

Flink doesn't support connecting multiple streams (specifically more than two) within a single operator. I think the most conventional pattern would be to simply chain the multiple broadcast streams consecutively via connect() within your job with associated process functions via a cascading pattern as follows:
streamEnv
    .connect(broadcastStream1)
    .process(...)
    .connect(broadcastStream2)
    .process(...)

If you need both broadcast-based elements to interact, you'd likely need to enrich or include some component from the first broadcast stream such that it could be connected with an element of the second stream.
Another possible option would be via the use of union() however that would require both of your streams to be of the same type and it likely wouldn't be conducive for broadcast streams.

Yeah, I did try to chain the broadcasts - but my requirement is, I need to first merge the two broadcasts before sending it off to the next phase. Also, they don't have a common key.

Is there no way of adding an additional property or adjusting the object being passed in the stream to accommodate this merge? For example adding a single property onto your object or using a Tuple and then performing the merge in the subsequent operation and just grabbing the object itself post-merge?
Without knowing more specifics about what's involved in the "merge" it's difficult to gauge what the ideal solution would be. I think you'd have to use this chained approach or consider unioning both of your existing broadcast streams into a single stream and broadcasting that.

I suggest looking for a way to combine the two streams via union, and then broadcast the result of the union. Depending on the types involved, that may or may not be straightforward, but if that's workable, it could yield a clean solution.
Broadcast streams are always streams of Map<Key, Value>, so this means reconciling/unifying the key and value types of those two streams.
